# crontab fails in fresh installation

Tags: pi-4, cron

looking for quick answer.
Fresh install of RPi, installed a couple of libraries to support my code. ran code successfully.
Tried to create a bootstrap using crontab to automatically load and run my code as a daemon. Has worked on previous installs.
My CLI was:
@reboot python /home/pi/AutoBootProg.py &
exit 0
My code was in the specified folder.

crontab -e failed both as Pi or root user.
here is print out of crontab being run.

no crontab for pi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.

1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
2. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
3. /bin/ed

Choose 1-3 [1]: 1
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.fBLEvt/crontab":26: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) y
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.fBLEvt/crontab":26: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.fBLEvt/crontab
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ crontab -l
no crontab for pi
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo crontab -l
no crontab for root
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

How do I format text in this forum editor.

Comment: Formatting cheat sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M51m.png; and more in-depth: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: If you'll remember this, it's often the quickest answer you'll get: [Let me google that for you](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=bad+command+errors+in+crontab+file)